# Custom msbuild task output not recognized

Tags: msbuild, extend, msbuild-task, csproj

I have a custom msbuild task with an output parameter defined below

```
 public class DeployJavaScript : Task
{
    [Required]
    public ITaskItem[] SourceFiles { get; set; }

    [Output]
    public string Result { get; set; }

    #region Overrides of Task

    public override bool Execute()
    {
        foreach (var sourceFile in SourceFiles)
        {
        }
        Result = String.Format("Sucessfully Deployed Javascript Files");
        return true;
    }

    #endregion Overrides of Task
}
```

In my build script(csproj file) I extend msbuild by injecting my custom task in the AfterBuild target as defined below

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
<Message Text="AfterBuild Begin" Importance="high"/>
<PropertyGroup>
  <JavaScriptFolderPath Condition=" '$(JavaScriptFolderPath)' == '' " >$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\</JavaScriptFolderPath>
  <JavaScriptFilePath></JavaScriptFilePath>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <JavaScriptFolderFiles Include="$(JavaScriptFolderPath)\**\*.js"/>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <JavaScriptFiles Include="$(JavaScriptFilePath)"/>
</ItemGroup>
<DeployJavaScript SourceFiles="@(JavaScriptFolderFiles->'%(FullPath)')">
  <Output TaskParameter="Result" PropertyName="ResultofJavaScriptDeployment"/>
</DeployJavaScript>
<Message Text="$(ResultofJavaScriptDeployment)" Importance="high"/>
<Message Text="AfterBuild Complete" Importance="high"/>
```

However, msbuild complains "Unknown output parameter Result,'DeployJavaScript' should have no output parameters"

Why I cannot return an output parameter in this scenario?

P.S
I know I can use Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.high,"sucess",high) to log the result in the proj file which would serve my purpose. Just want to know why I cannot use an output parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the type of the `Result` property in your code. Use `ITaskItem` instead of `string`. For me it helped to solve the same problem.
Naturally, your code will have to create an instance of `TaskItem` class after that:
`Result = new TaskItem(String.Format("Sucessfully Deployed Javascript Files"));`